# Is there a better way of decoding a json in C# where the name of the key varies?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, json-deserialization

I have a response from an external api that looks like this, if i send in properties like this:

```
{ 
 "color": "blue"
 "type": "dog"
}
```

and then if i enter an invalid value of any of these i get a short error message back and a longer description for the property i sent in that was wrong. So lets say i send in

```
{ 
 "color": "blue"
 "type": "banana"
}
```

I would get

```
{
  "problem": "invalid pet",
  "type": "banana is not a valid type of pet ",
  "messageProperties": [
   "color",
   "type" ]
}
```

Then if i send in

```
{
  "color": "banana",
  "type: "dog"
}
```

I would get

```
{
  "problem": "wrong pet color",
  "color": "banana is not a valid color for a pet",
   "messageProperties": [
   "color",
   "type" ]
}
```

Is there an easy way of handling this? The best solution i found so far feels overly complex. Is there a better way? I'm using .NET  6

```
    public class MyErrorClass
    {
        public MyErrorClass(string json)
        {
            
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> kw in ((JObject)((JContainer)data)))
            {
                switch (kw.Key)
                {
                    case "context":
                        context = (string) kw.Value;
                        break;
                    case "messageProperties":
                    {
                        List<JToken> children = kw.Value.Children().ToList();
                        messageVariables = children.Values<string>().ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        error = (string) kw.Value;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        public string context { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
        public List<string> messageVariables { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: 15 lines of code is ‘overly complex’?

Comment: I was hoping for JSON.MakeANiceClassOutOfThis() or something.

Comment: I would recommend to change `dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);` to `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);` or `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);`. While `dynamic` exists in C# I would recommend avoid using it whenever is possible.

Comment: I would change the reply messages, so they always return the same structure, like: `"error": 'type': banana is not a valid type of pet"` instead of: `"type": "banana is not a valid type of pet ",`. Then you can always use the same class to deserialize.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking. What does "handle this" mean, "this" what? Sending a JSON response in that format? That's trivial, what's the problem? Receiving it? That's again trivial, it's literally decoded for you, just ask your `JObject` what properties it has. What are you even doing storing errors and "message variables..?" in your ..what even is that class, it's not a model and not a controller, what is it? *What are you doing*?

Comment: @PoulBak I have no control over how I receive the message from the external API so I can not change it.

Comment: @Blindy I want to decode the response into a class with a "message" property that describes the issue to humans and an error code (the context part) that I can take actions on. The json response is sent by an external api as stated in my question so I can not alter that one.

Comment: @GuruStron good point, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use [`JsonExtensionData`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm). For example:

```cs
class Resp
{
    public string Problem { get; set; }
    public List<string> MessageProperties { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Extras { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;
    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Extras = _additionalData.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Or based on your example:

```
class MyErrorClass
{
    public string Problem { get; set; }
    public List<string> MessageProperties { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;
    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context) => Error = _additionalData?.FirstOrDefault().Value?.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Oh I had no idea you could do an OnDeserialize to override the process and map the extra fields with JsonExtensionData like that. Interesting!

Comment: @falowil was glad to help! Actually similar approach works for `System.Text.Json` too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Newtonsoft.JSON, you could import Newtonsoft.Json.Linq and perhaps use the following:

```
if(JObject.Parse(json).ContainsKey("problem"))
```

For objects you can also use something like:

```
.GetType().GetProperty("problem") // if != null, then property exists
```